# display form validation hint with form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this java script function to display a form validation hint. This function is working properly with input elements.. My problem is I need to modify this function with other form elements such as textarea, select box, checkbox... can anybody tell me how can I do this?

This is the function I have been using..

```
function prepareInputsForHints() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        // test to see if the hint span exists first
        if (inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
            // the span exists!  on focus, show the hint
            inputs[i].onfocus = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
            }
            // when the cursor moves away from the field, hide the hint
            inputs[i].onblur = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
    // repeat the same tests as above for selects
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var k=0; k<selects.length; k++){
        if (selects[k].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
            selects[k].onfocus = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
            }
            selects[k].onblur = function () {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is Html

```
<div>
    <label for="mobile">Mobile<img alt="required" src="images/required_star.png"> :</label>
    <input id="mobile" class="text" type="text" maxlength="10" name="mobile" title="Eg: 0714556260"/>
    <span class="hint">Use a 10 digits length number<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
</div>
```

I tried something like this with textarea but it is not working...

```
<div>
    <label for="qualification">Qualification Details<img alt="required" src="images/required_star.png">:</label>
    <textarea id="qualification" class="textarea" rows="4" cols="30" name="qualification"></textarea>
        <span class="hint">Describe about you<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to user jQuery...? It would make the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: can you modify this function with jquery? I am very new to Jquery.. so no idea how to do this this jquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".hint").css({ "display":"none" });
$("input.hint_needed, select.hint_needed, textarea.hint_needed, radio.hint_needed").on("mouseenter", function() {
$(".hint").css({ "display":"inline" });
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
$(".hint").css({ "display":"none" });
});
});​

<textarea id="qualification" class="hint_needed" rows="4" cols="30" name="qualification"></textarea>
```

you can use this!

http://jsfiddle.net/QD3Hn/1/

Comment: when I add this to code to my page.. and clicking on a form element every hint message display on the page. even not insert hint class to the element. why is it..

Comment: man you want only those elements to show hint which also have class hint?

Comment: thanks for response.. but with that code cant get hint message to display.

Comment: oh man sorry you can set the classes of elements to `hint_needed` and then i edited my answer :)

Comment: but there is a problem..when I mouse move on to a form element every hint message display on the form..that mean other elements hint message also display in the same time.. why is it?

Comment: thank for your help.. it is working now. but have a problem with wordcounter function. I added it to new post.. this is the link for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898562/working-validation-hint-working-word-counter-but-not-working-together

Comment: can I add a animation to this..?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Per OP's request, allow hints to be displayed on hover as well.

Here's what I have based on non-jQuery implementation of the code:
(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E9njP/)

```
<div>
    <label for="mobile">Mobile* :</label>
    <input id="mobile" class="text" type="text" maxlength="10" name="mobile" />
    <span class="hint">Use a 10 digits length number</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="qualification">Qualification Details*:</label>
    <textarea id="qualification" class="textarea" rows="4" cols="30" name="qualification"></textarea>
    <span class="hint">Describe about you</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="dropdown">Dropdown*:</label>
    <select id="dropdown"><option>A</option><option>B</option></select>
    <span class="hint">Hints for Select</span>
</div>

<!-- This is just for demo purpose -->
<div>
    <label>Tricky Input:</label>
    <input/>
    <span>Don't hide me! I am not a hint!</span>
</div>
```

... Instead of doing CSS on the element, I'm using CSS instead. Here are the classes...

```
div span.hint {
    display: none;
}

div span.over,
div span.focus {
    display: inline;
}
```

... and here's the javascript ...

```
(function() {
    // Since it's likely that you'll only ever run this function once 
    // (Once you attached the events, you'll probably never reuse this 
    // function again), I put it inside an IIFE to keep it "clean".

    /**
     * Toggle class on element without jQuery...
     *
     * @param {DOMElement} el Element to apply CSS to
     * @param {string} css CSS class name to be applied
     * @param {boolean} on Determine whether class name should be on the element or not
     **/
    function getHandler(el, css, on) {
        return function() {
            // If we want to add CSS to the element, and it doesn't exist on the
            // element yet, add it.
            if (on && el.className.indexOf(css) === -1) {
                el.className += ' ' + css;
            }
            // If we want to remove CSS from the element, and it exists, remove
            // it.
            else if (!on && el.className.indexOf(css) >= 0) {
                el.className = el.className.replace(css, '');
            }

            // NOTE This solution will lead to extra spacing in CSS name...
        };
    }

    function setHandler(inputEl, hintEl) {
        // the span exists!  on focus, show the hint
        inputEl.onfocus = getHandler(hintEl, "focus", true);
        inputEl.onmouseover = getHandler(hintEl, "over", true);

        // when the cursor moves away from the field, hide the hint
        inputEl.onblur = getHandler(hintEl, "focus", false);
        inputEl.onmouseout = getHandler(hintEl, "over", false);
    }

    function prepareHintsByTag(tag) {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
            // test to see if the hint span exists first
            if (inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
                var hintEl = inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

                // Show "hint" only if it has the class of "hint"
                if (hintEl.className.indexOf("hint") === 0) {
                    setHandler(inputs[i], hintEl);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Scan the code     
    prepareHintsByTag("input");
    prepareHintsByTag("textarea");
    prepareHintsByTag("select");
})();
    ​
```

Added couple of things to the code...

- By default, the hints should probably be hidden. I made that a default in CSS.
- Added a check to see if the "span" class is of "hint" before toggling the CSS. (Just so you won't hide something that wasn't intended!)
- I refactored the prepareHint function so it's reusable for SELECT, INPUT and TEXTAREA.
- I put the function that handles prepare hints in an IIFE, since it's likely that you'll only do this one. You can read more about IIFE here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/
- Instead of doing style manipulation on the element's style directly, I moved those to CSS classes. It should make more sense hopefully...

This is, again, the non-jQuery version - There are more rooms for improvements, but hopefully this would be sufficient for your task.

Comment: can you tell me how display hint when someone move mouse on to a form element.. not click.. Now we need to click the form element to see hint. .