# working validation hint, working word counter but not working together

Tags: jquery

I added a word counter to a my form's textarea... it is something like this...

```
<div>
  <label>About you:</label>
  <textarea id="qualification" class="textarea hint_needed" rows="4" cols="30" ></textarea>                     
  <span class="hint">explain about you</span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("textarea").textareaCounter();
  </script>
</div>
```

My problem is when I add textaracounter() like this my validation hint is not working.. when I remover the counter function validation hint is working...

this is the jquery for hint message..

```
$(".hint").css({ "display":"none" });
$("input.hint_needed, select.hint_needed, textarea.hint_needed, radio.hint_needed").on("mouseenter", function() {
$(this).next(".hint").css({ "display":"inline" });
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
$(this).next(".hint").css({ "display":"none" });
});
```

this is for the word counter..

```
(function($){
    $.fn.textareaCounter = function(options) {
        // setting the defaults
        // $("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
        var defaults = {
            limit: 150
        };  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // and the plugin begins
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj, text, wordcount, limited;

            obj = $("#experience");
            obj.after('<span style="font-weight: bold; color:#6a6a6a; clear: both; margin: 3px 0 0 150px; float: left; overflow: hidden;" id="counter-text">Max. '+options.limit+' words</span>');

            obj.keyup(function() {
                text = obj.val();
                if(text === "") {
                    wordcount = 0;
                } else {
                    wordcount = $.trim(text).split(" ").length;
                }
                if(wordcount > options.limit) {
                    $("#counter-text").html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');
                    limited = $.trim(text).split(" ", options.limit);
                    limited = limited.join(" ");
                    $(this).val(limited);
                } else {
                    $("#counter-text").html((options.limit - wordcount)+' words left');
                } 
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

can anybody tell me what is the problem there?

Thank you..

Comment: `obj = $("#experience");` why it is here in plugin ?

Comment: textarea also closed incorrect

Comment: Can you demonstrate in a fiddle, preferably without the typos and missing IDs?

Comment: obj = $("#experience"); should be obj = $("textarea"); but it is not working...

Comment: @SriyaniRathnayaka your wrong, in plugin should be no direct selectors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QD3Hn/6/

Comment: @eicto Im not clear your comment. can you elaborate it?

Comment: Why do you use `.css()` instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`?

Comment: @Barmar I wrote the code of `.css()` because he wanted it like that!

Comment: @AspiringAqib My question was to the OP, not you.

Comment: Hey, I answered because I wrote and gave him the code of that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QD3Hn/14/         `// without improvements`

```
(function($){
    $.fn.textareaCounter = function(options) {
        // setting the defaults
        // $("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
        var defaults = {
            limit: 150
        };  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // and the plugin begins
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj, text, wordcount, limited;

            obj = $(this);
            obj.next(".hint").after('<span style="font-weight: bold; color:#6a6a6a; clear: both; margin: 3px 0 0 150px; float: left; overflow: hidden;" id="counter-text">Max. '+options.limit+' words</span>');

            obj.on("keyup keydown", function() {
                text = obj.val();
                if(text === "") {
                    wordcount = 0;
                } else {
                    wordcount = obj.val().split(" ").length;
                }
                if(wordcount == options.limit) {
                    obj.next(".hint").next("#counter-text").html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');
                    limited = $.trim(text).split(" ", options.limit);
                    limited = limited.join(" ");
                    $(this).val(limited);
                } else {
                    obj.next(".hint").next("#counter-text").html((options.limit - wordcount)+' words left');
                } 
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".hint").css({ "display":"none" });
    $("input.hint_needed, select.hint_needed, textarea.hint_needed, radio.hint_needed").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).next(".hint").css({ "display":"inline" });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).next(".hint").css({ "display":"none" });
    });
        $("textarea").textareaCounter();
    });​
```

Comment: woah man whoever downvoted my answer please tell me my mistake :)

Comment: it is incorrect  - direct selects in plugin, what if here two textareas ?

Comment: You should describe what you changed to fix it, not just post the entire code. Do you expect everyone to perform a diff to learn from this?

Comment: see how your 'plugin' works with [two textareas](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QD3Hn/13/)... and how [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/MfHMB/)

Comment: @AspiringAqib using `.after(` each time and, below in the code traversing the DOM to search for the same element, not the smartest idea I saw in my life

Comment: hey `.after()` is not used by me. It already had it in code. So, manipulated it according :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21204/discussion-between-eicto-and-aspiring-aqib)

Answer (score 0):

I will comment code:

```
(function($) {
    var defaults = {
        limit: 150
    };

    $.fn.textareaCounter = function(options) {
        // setting the defaults
        // $("textarea").textareaCounter({ limit: 100 });
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // and the plugin begins
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj, text, wordcount, limited, counter_text;
            //TEXTAREA, current one
            obj = $(this);
            //setup counter text only once, do not recreate it
            if (counter_text === undefined) {
                //better to set class here, but will work
                counter_text=$('<span style="font-weight: bold; color:#6a6a6a; clear: both; margin: 3px 0 0 150px; float: left; overflow: hidden;" id="counter-text">');
                obj.after(counter_text);
            }
            counter_text.text('Max. ' + options.limit + ' words');
            //for better handling of paste you can refer to my other answer: http://tinyurl.com/bvtjoa7
            obj.bind('keyup input',function(e) {
                text = obj.val();
                if (text === "") {
                    wordcount = 0;
                } else {
                    wordcount = $.trim(text).split(" ").length;
                }
                //I added the code here to check for space key, for better usability
                if (wordcount > options.limit || (wordcount==options.limit && e.keyCode == 32 )) {
                    counter_text.html('<span style="color: #DD0000;">0 words left</span>');
                    limited = $.trim(text).split(" ", options.limit);
                    limited = limited.join(" ");
                    $(this).val(limited);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    counter_text.html((options.limit - wordcount) + ' words left');
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

//HINT
$(".hint").css({
    "display": "none"
});

$("input,textarea,select").filter('.hint_needed').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".hint").css({
        "display": "inline"
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".hint").css({
        "display": "none"
    });
});  
//END OF HINT

//run with limit of 3 words
$("textarea").textareaCount({
  limit: 3
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/MfHMB/)

Comment: I just missed that part, fixed answer

Comment: btw, `on` will not work here as expected, `bind` will, `on` is replacement for `live`, so it should be binded to document, or parent element, in sample `on` will work like `bind`

Comment: using `nextAll` should add `eq(0)` or `first()` just in case tree includes all the hints on same level

Comment: would assume point is only to show hint for that specific elemnt...but might work either way. I need to use `nextAll` more often... handy in situations like this, but I rarely use it as you can see by my idea

Comment: can I know.. how can I apply this counter function for a specific element.. that mean I have more textarea in my form and now this function working for all those..just I need to apply this counter function for one textarea....

Comment: use special selector, id of textarea or class `$("#qualification")` at your case

Comment: hey everybody i got the solution, no need of commenting now!

Comment: @AspiringAqib :) want me to review your solution again ?

Answer (score 0):

the main issue is your textarea plugin adds an element `after` the textarea. This means that the `next()` in your `mousenter` isn't the `hint` class you expect it to be, because of the newly added span.

`next()` looks for the next immediate sibling... which is now the textAreaCounter span

If you were to wrap the textArea in another element like a span you could change the hint code to:

```
$(".hint_needed").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    var $this=$(this), $next= $this.is('textarea') ? $this.parent().next() : $this.next();

    $next.toggle();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/QD3Hn/12/